# Pass Different Parameter Types to One Function that Share Functions

Tags: java

So I've got two object that are entirely different excluding the fact they have some common fields and I'm trying to cut down my code by using a function that would only reference these common fields.

For example, one class is called Soccer.
Soccer has these fields:
-Player
-BallCnt
-Team
-Coach
-Time
-Shoes

Next is Lacrosse having these fields:
-Player
-Team
-Rules
-Coach
-Time

I'm trying to make a function that would take both sports but would only reference the fields in common so it can just be referenced with `map += getCommon(map, soccer);` I.e.

```
public Map<String, String> getCommon(Map<S, S> map, Object o){
    map.put("coach", o.getCoach());
    map.put("player", o.getPlayer());
    etc...
    return map;
}
```

This way if I add another class in the future it can still share the common fields. My first thought was using a generic for the second function but those are iffy for me.

Comment: Welcome to OOP! Catch up on some basics and I bet the answer will seem obvious. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-oriented-programming-oops-concept-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want an [Interface](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_interface.asp), which is a type of Java abstract class. You can create an interface that contains your shared methods. For example a `Sport` interface like this:

```
interface Sport {
    public String getPlayer();
    public String getCoach();
    
}
```

Then your concrete classes will have to implement the interface, which will force them to all have the methods from the interface:

```
class Soccer implements Sport
{

    String player = "Soccer Player";
    String coach = "Soccer Coach";

    // This attribute is unique to the Soccer class
    String shoes;
    
    // These methods are required by the interface
    public String getPlayer(){
        return player;
    }
    public String getCoach(){
        return coach;
    }
}


class Lacrosse implements Sport
{

    String player = "Lacrosse Player";
    String coach = "Lacrosse Coach";

    // This attribute is unique to the Lacrosse class
    String Rules;
    
    // These methods are required by the interface
    public String getPlayer(){
        return player;
    }
    public String getCoach(){
        return coach;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `Sport` interface to guarantee that the concrete classes will have the shared methods.

```
public Map<String, String> getCommon(Map<S, S> map, Sport o){
    map.put("coach", o.getCoach());
    map.put("player", o.getPlayer());
    etc...
    return map;
}
```

You can now call the `getCommon` method with either a `Soccer` object or a `Lacrosse` object.

```
    // assuming the maps already exist
    Soccer soc = new Soccer();
    Lacrosse lac = new Lacrosse();
    getCommon(socMap, soc);
    getCommon(lacMap, lac);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a super class called "TeamSport" with the parameters player, team, coach and time. In this class you would make that method which adds to a map on all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are not the way to go. You need two or more classes (Soccer and Lacrosse) based on one common ancestor (Game). This common ancestor may be another "normal" **class** (in this context called a "superclass"), an **abstract class** (also called a "superclass") or an **interface**.

You only use a normal **class** as the ancestor when you want to (directly) instantiate it. If you don't (that is, if you'll create instances of Soccer and/or Lacrosse, but not instances of Game), you use an **abstract class** or an **interface**. There are several differences between these two, but the more important is that each (sub)class can *inherit* from only one (super)class, which may be "normal" or abstract; but it can *implement* any number of interfaces. (Another key difference is that "classic" interfaces are just blueprints that don't include code; but this restriction was recently relaxed.)

In this sample code, I chose to use an *abstract class* as the ancestor (but this *may* not be the best choice for your actual problem). I also chose to put the `getCommon()` function inside the ancestor (but it could be a "stand-alone" function). I used a map for storing the data of each "game", and a list for containing all the maps (but this is unrelated with your core question).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

abstract class Game {
  String coach;
  String player;
  
  String getCoach() { return coach; }
  String getPlayer() { return player; }
  
  Map<String, String> getCommon () {
    var map = new HashMap<String, String> ();
    
    map.put("coach", getCoach());
    map.put("player", getPlayer());
    
    return map;
  }
}

class Soccer extends Game
{
  Soccer (String league, String team, String coach, String player) { this.league = league; this.team = team; this.coach = coach; this.player = player; time = LocalTime.now(); }
  int ballCnt;
  String league;
  String team;
  String shoes;
  LocalTime time;
}

class Lacrosse extends Game
{
  Lacrosse (String team, String coach, String player) { this.team = team; this.coach = coach; this.player = player; time = LocalTime.now(); }
  String team;
  String rules[];
  LocalTime time;
}

void main(String[] args) {
  Soccer soccers[] = {
    new Soccer("League 1", "Team 1", "John Smith", "Mike"),
    new Soccer("League 1", "Team 1", "John Smith", "Peter"),
    new Soccer("League 1", "Team 2", "Alan Jones", "Charly")
  };
  
  Lacrosse lacrossers[] = {
    new Lacrosse("We play alone!", "We don't need one!", "Mary"),  
    new Lacrosse("We play alone!", "We don't need one!", "Susan")
  };
  
  // Create a List<>. Each element will be the Map<> of a soccer, lacrosser, etc 
  var list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>> ();
  
  // Create a map for each "soccer" and add it to the common list
  for (var s : soccers)  
    list.add (s.getCommon());
  
  // Create a map for each "lacrosser" and add it to the common list
  for (var l : lacrossers)  
    list.add (l.getCommon());
  
  // Dump the list
  for (var element : list) {
    for (var entry : element.entrySet())
      System.out.println (entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
    System.out.println ();
  }
}
```

The output is:

> coach: John Smith
> player: Mike
>
> coach: John Smith
> player: Peter
>
> coach: Alan Jones
> player: Charly
>
> coach: We don't need one!
> player: Mary
>
> coach: We don't need one!
> player: Susan